# Launching an .xib from a class with no reference to the navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In a class file I am needing to launch an new `.xib` file when a `UIButton` is clicked.

I have tried a few things all to no avail. I am thinking the best(?) way of doing this is going to be by using a `UINavigationController` to push a view to.

What I have tried (which isnt working) is:

```
-(void)btnSubmitPic{

    UINavigationController *frameWindow = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    ViewControllerContactUs *vc = [[ViewControllerContactUs alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerContactUs" bundle:nil];

    [frameWindow pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

I have tried several different versions of this; nothing seems to be working.

Does anybody have any knowledge of how to push a view to the screen when you have no reference to the `self.view`?

**Edit:**

I have referenced the previous view controller, however it is not launching when doing so:

```
-(void)btnSubmitPic{

    ViewControllerContactUs *vc = [[ViewControllerContactUs alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerContactUs" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"PREV VC: %@", prevVC);

    [prevVC.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

When doing the NSLog there, `prevVC`  = `<ViewController: 0x13550f9b0>` which is correct.

Comment: Since this method is an event handler for a button, are you inside a UIViewController? Or is this method declared inside some NSObject class?

You're just pushing a UIViewController onto a UINavigationController but never presenting that UINavigationController

Comment: The method is declared in an `NSObject` class; and the class can be called from any `viewcontroller` (present from all).

Comment: The navigation controller you created is not in your view controller hierarchy (it's view is not even added to the window at all), so of course it's not going to do anything. You need a reference to a view controller to present ViewControllerContactUs (or navigation controller if you want to push). You should create a delegate protocol in this class, and have the controller that calls this class, set itself as the delegate.

Comment: @rdelmar I see, is there no way to create a `UIWindow` push it to that and dismiss it when done? (the xib it loads is a one time use type thing). The way you suggest, any ideas how i can do this when the `NSObject` class is called from any `ViewController` ?

Comment: I said how to do it in my comment. When any controller creates an instance of this class, the controller sets itself as the delegate. You need to implement a delegate protocol in this NSObject subclass that has a method that tells the delegate it should present this new controller.

Comment: You're not referencing the previous view controller, you're creating  a new instance of it. You need to read some documentation, and learn how to create and use a delegate protocol.

Answer (score 0):

One approach here could be to present the view controller modally on the apps root view controller.

you can try this

```
-(void)btnSubmitPic
{
    ViewControllerContactUs *vc = [[ViewControllerContactUs alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerContactUs" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```